# In the same matrix, how do you re-organize the order of numbers of the first column?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix:

```
a =
[26 709,107666000000

 41 2839,29345700000

 56 5572,19531300000

 70 8802,29882800000

 84 12283,4667970000

 98 15999,8603520000

 38 1715,02050800000

 49 4174,55908200000

 63 7141,78564500000

 79 10481,1035160000

 91 14136,5742190000

 105 17840,5800780000
]
```

I need to reorganize the matrix in ascending order assuming the first column as order.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to read and explore this - http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/sort.html

Comment: The first column is already sorted. Can you give the example output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SortRows:

```
sorting_column=1;
a=sortrows(a,sorting_column);
```

Answer (score 2):

use the function [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html)

When called with only a single input argument, `sortrows` bases the sort on the first column of the matrix. For any rows that have equal elements in a particular column, sorting is based on the column immediately to the right.